# Microsoft Word deletes a space along with the word when pressing Ctrl+Backspace. How do I prevent it from removing the space?

Tags: microsoft-word

Consider the following text, with the cursor placed at the end of the text (in place of where the vertical bar is):

```
Don't test me sunshine|
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will yield the following in certain cases (e.g. when there is a space/more words after the cursor):

```
Don't test me|
```

I would much rather prefer the following result (with the space in place):

```
Don't test me |
```

Is there an option where I can force this behaviour?

Comment: Use the other keyboard shortcut for delete word, CTRL+Backspace and then Space.

Comment: Out of all the programs I use, Microsoft Word is the only one I noticed that deletes the space with Ctrl + Backspace. Very strange and annoying - wish there was a better solution than the marked answer.

Comment: Outlook also has this behaviour for me unfortunately. And I believe it hasn‘t been there always and only since 2010 (but maybe I remember this wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is considered a feature (as most users would also want the space removed). I don't know of anyway to configure the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> behavior.

One alternative would be to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to highlight the word. Then press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I expected this. Though I wasn't aware of the word highlight shortcut, that might be useful.

Comment: _"as most users would also want the space removed"_ **Why?** This has always bugged me and I'm not sure about the rationale behind it. 99.99% of the times I use `Ctrl+ Backspace`, it's because I want to remove the previous word _and type a new one_. I use that shortcut everywhere and MS-Word is the only program where I encountered this behavior.

Answer (score 12):

After some hunting on the net, I found this feature ***is*** optional (kind of).

> Word options->Advanced->Cut, Copy and Paste->Use smart cut and paste->Settings->Adjust sentence and word spacing automatically.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_windows8/control-backspace-deletes-previous-word-and-the/aa87aa3d-5928-4dd1-9266-b914f9c14620?auth=1

---

**Note**: This solves the problem when writing a *new* paragraph, but when deleting words with more words following it the same default behaviour occurs.

For example (if `|` represents the cursor/"insertion point"):

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet|

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> works as normal (with or without a space before the cursor):

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit |

But in the case of:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit| amet

With the cursor directly after the word to be deleted, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will result in Word's default behaviour:

> Lorem ipsum dolor| amet

As far as I can tell this isn't in the settings, so bear in mind that there's a bit of inconsistent behaviour if `Adjust sentence and word spacing automatically` is turned off.

Comment: It's probably not as common as you might think and it's behavior is a matter of opinion. Your suggestion would mean that a user that wants to remove a work would have to hit Backspace and additional time after removing a word in order to avoid a double space. There are pros and cons to both behaviors.

Comment: @Seth you're right, I can see why the inconsistent behaviour might be preferable for some. Personally, the reason I see this is as undesirable is because not removing the space is the default behaviour for all of the applications that I do a lot of typing in (browsers, text editors, IDEs, etc.). The typing style I've come to adopt involves a lot of `Ctrl` + `Backspace` to fix spelling errors or replace words, whether that's at the end of a paragraph or in the middle of one. It's frustrating for me to then go write in Word and have to interrupt myself to insert extra spaces.

Comment: Not really a solution but maybe an acceptable workaround? Mark the word using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Left Arrow` and afterwards delete it using either `Del` or `Backspace`. Suggestion from the answers of that question: [Microsoft Word deletes a space along with the word when pressing Ctrl+Backspace. How do I prevent it from removing the space?](http://superuser.com/questions/585522/microsoft-word-deletes-a-space-along-with-the-word-when-pressing-ctrlbackspace)

Answer (score 3):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is the desired behaviour:

1. Create a macro of that behaviour, in Word press `Alt+F11`
2. Under Normal, `Right click` on the Modules folder, then `Insert` > `Module`
3. Paste the below macro [Should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBsLz.png)
4. Assign it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

   (File --> Options --> Customize Ribbon --> Keyboard Shortcuts: Customize...
   Categories: Macros
   Find your newly created macro

**Macro:**

```vb
Sub CtrlBackspace()  
'  
' CtrlBackspace Macro
'
'
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.TypeBackspace
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> also erases the space before the word. The best solution is already given; once the automatic word spacing is disabled, this functions as expected.

Answer (score -1):

This behaviour ceases entirely if you disable smart cut and paste in Advanced settings. Edit: turns out that's only for cut and paste, delete displays the aforementioned incomplete functionality.

Comment: This information has already been given in a previous answer.

Comment: Actually, I thought I had found an upgrade.